# Convert text value ( 6/1/2018 11:34:33 PM , 6/2/2018 2:32:07 AM) to timestamp

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.2

I have a column with text datatype in PostgreSQL with values below:

```
6/1/2018 11:34:33 PM
6/2/2018 2:32:07 AM
```

I want to convert it to timestamp:

```
2018-01-06 23:34:333
2018-02-06 02:32:07
```

How do I do it?

I tried `to_timestamp(entry_time_stamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss')` but it does not add PM value to it.

Answer (score 0):

use : 
to_timestamp(entry_time_stamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:mi:ss **AM**')